# Add header to all tabs on a tab control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Say you had a header that all tabs of a `tabcontrol` needed (e.g. there were six tabs), for example:

> My Header

How would you programmaticaly add a header (maybe generate / create a label) to all of the tab pages?

Comment: Can you define what "header" means in this context?  Picture might help here.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do this.

It seems completely redundant to append the same prefix to *all* of the tabs in a tab control. Not only is redundancy bad, but it makes the information hard to parse for the user. You're hiding the important thing (what's different) *behind* something that is unimportant (what's the same). Additionally, if your control is made smaller and there isn't enough room to display the full tab labels, they'll be truncated from the rear, meaning that it's very likely there won't be enough room to display the different information on the screen, making it completely impossible for the user to figure out which tab they want.

The better solution would be to place a Label control just *above* the tab control with whatever header you want to display. That way, it would be obvious to the user that all of the tabs in the tab control have some common association, while still allowing you to use the tab labels judiciously in displaying the pieces that make them distinct.

If you *must* do this, use a `for` or `foreach` loop to insert your desired text at the beginning of the label (exposed via the `Text` property) for each of the individual tab pages displayed in your tab control.